# Right click Open Contex Menu on Layer Silverlight 3.2

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight, model-view-viewmodel

How I can Open a RadContextMenu (telerik) When User Click on Layer (Feature Layer / Graphic Layer) and allow user to do different task etal : Show Details of Geometry, Edit Option For Geometry, Edit/Delete Other information for Graphic. other Task Like Running Code Behind & doing Db changes etc.

My Application is in Prism 4.2 &  MVVM. ArcGIS Silverlight 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Its Late but I solved it Some How.i forgot the Blog Link for Code Behing Context menu via Telerik blogs

Custom ContextMenu Class:

```
  public abstract class ContextMenu
{
    private Point _location;
    private bool _isShowing;
    private System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup _popup;
    private Grid _grid;
    private Canvas _canvas;
    private FrameworkElement _content;

    //Initialize and display the pop-up form. Public method is called when a menu item is displayed 
    public void Show(Point location)
    {
        if (_isShowing)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        _isShowing = true;
        _location = location;
        ConstructPopup();
        _popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    //Close pop-up window  
    public void Close()
    {
        _isShowing = false;
        if (_popup != null)
        {
            _popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    //abstract function that the child class needs to implement to return the framework element that needs to be displayed in the popup window.  
    protected abstract FrameworkElement GetContent();

    //Default behavior for OnClickOutside() is to close the context menu when there is a mouse click event outside the context menu  
    protected virtual void OnClickOutside()
    {
        Close();
    }

    // To use Grid layout , initialize the pop form
    //In the Grid which added a Canvas, for outside monitoring menu item mouse click events  
    //  
    // Add the Framework Element returned by GetContent() to the grid and position it at _location  
    private void ConstructPopup()
    {
        if (_popup != null)
            return;
        _popup = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup();
        _grid = new Grid();
        _popup.Child = _grid;
        _canvas = new Canvas();
        _canvas.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, args) => { OnClickOutside(); };
        _canvas.MouseRightButtonDown += (sender, args) => { args.Handled = true; OnClickOutside(); };
        _canvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        _grid.Children.Add(_canvas);
        _content = GetContent();
        _content.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        _content.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        _content.Margin = new Thickness(_location.X, _location.Y, 0, 0);
        _grid.Children.Add(_content);
        UpdateSize();
    }

    /// <summary>  
    /// Update Size
    /// </summary>  
    private void UpdateSize()
    {
        _grid.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
        _grid.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
        if (_canvas != null)
        {
            _canvas.Width = _grid.Width;
            _canvas.Height = _grid.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

ContextMenuItem Class

```
    public class ContextMenuItem : ViewModelBase
{
    public ContextMenuItem()
    {
        this.SubItems = new ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem>();
    }

    private Decimal _Id;
    public Decimal Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            _Id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Id);
        }
    }

    private string _Text;
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _Text;
        }
        set
        {
            _Text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Text);
        }
    }
    private Uri _IconUrl;
    public Uri IconUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return _IconUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            _IconUrl = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IconUrl);
        }
    }
    private bool _IsSeparator;
    public bool IsSeparator
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsSeparator;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsSeparator = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSeparator);
        }
    }
    private ICommand _Command;
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return _Command;
        }
        set
        {
            _Command = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Command);
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem> _SubItems;
    public ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem> SubItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _SubItems;
        }
        set
        {
            _SubItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SubItems);
        }
    }
    private object _CommandParameter;
    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return _CommandParameter;
        }
        set
        {
            _CommandParameter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CommandParameter);
        }
    }
}
```

RightContextMapMenu Class

```
  public class RightContextMapMenu : ContextMenu
{
    public RightContextMapMenu()
    {

    }
    public RightContextMapMenu(ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem> MapContextMenuItems)
    {
        this.MapContextMenuItems = MapContextMenuItems;
    }
    protected FrameworkElement GetContentRad()
    {
        return null;
    }

    private RadContextMenu BuildContextMenu()
    {
        RadContextMenu contextMenu = new RadContextMenu();
        contextMenu.ItemContainerStyle = Application.Current.Resources["HpmMapItemsMenuItemContainer"] as Style;
        contextMenu.ItemsSource = InitializeRowContextMenuItems();
        return contextMenu;
    }
    private ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem> InitializeRowContextMenuItems()
    {
        if (MapContextMenuItems == null)
        {
            ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem> items = new ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem>();
            ContextMenuItem gmapMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem();
            gmapMenuItem.Id = 1;
            gmapMenuItem.Text = "Google Map ";
            gmapMenuItem.Command = new DelegateCommand(OnGoogleMapOpen, CanGoogleMapOpen);
            items.Add(gmapMenuItem);
            //for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            //{
            //    ContextMenuItem ctx = new ContextMenuItem();
            //    ctx.Id = i;
            //    ctx.Text = "Hola" + i;
            //    ctx.Command = new DelegateCommand(OnContextMenuItemCommand, CanContextMenuItemCommand);
            //    ctx.CommandParameter = i;
            //    items.Add(ctx);
            //}
            return items;
        }
        else
        {
            return MapContextMenuItems;
        }


    }

    public ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem> MapContextMenuItems { get; set; }

    private void OnGoogleMapOpen(object obj)
    {

    }

    private bool CanGoogleMapOpen(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private bool CanContextMenuItemCommand(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void OnContextMenuItemCommand(object obj)
    {

    }

   // Construct a menu button and return to a FrameworkElement object  
    protected override FrameworkElement GetContent()
    {
        return BuildContextMenu();
    }
}
```

Style Code:

```
  <!-- RIGHT CLICK MENU-->
   <Style x:Key="HpmMapItemsMenuItemContainer" TargetType="telerik:RadMenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding IconUrl}"/>
    <Setter Property="IconTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="None"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="IsSeparator" Value="{Binding IsSeparator}"/>
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SubItems}"/>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}"/>
</Style>
```

At Map Right Click Event Command Bing with MVVMLight

```
   public MainMap(){
      MapRightContextMenu = CreateMapRightMenu();
       this.MouseRightButtonDownCommand = new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand<object>(OnMouseRightButtonDownCommand, CanMouseRightButtonDownCommand);

   }
  public RightContextMapMenu CreateMapRightMenu()
    {
        RightContextMapMenu menu = new RightContextMapMenu();
        menu.MapContextMenuItems = createRightClickMapMenu();
        return menu;
    }

    private RightContextMapMenu _MapRightContextMenu;
    public RightContextMapMenu MapRightContextMenu
    {
        get
        {
            return _MapRightContextMenu;
        }
        set
        {
            _MapRightContextMenu = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MapRightContextMenu);
        }
    }
 /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CanMouseRightButtonDownCommand(object arg)
    {
        return true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// At Right Click
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    private void OnMouseRightButtonDownCommand(object obj)
    {
        MouseButtonEventArgs args = obj as MouseButtonEventArgs;
        Point mapPoint=args.GetPosition(BaseVm.HpmMap.Parent as UIElement);
        args.Handled = true;
        if (MapRightContextMenu != null)
        {
            MapRightContextMenu.Show(mapPoint);
        }

    }

    private ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem> createRightClickMapMenu()
    {
        ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem> items = new ObservableCollection<ContextMenuItem>();
        ContextMenuItem gmapMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem();
        gmapMenuItem.Id = 1;
        gmapMenuItem.Text = "Google Map ";
        items.Add(gmapMenuItem);
        ContextMenuItem gmapMenuItem1 = new ContextMenuItem();
        gmapMenuItem.Id = 2;
        gmapMenuItem.Text = "Youtube Map ";
        items.Add(gmapMenuItem1);
        return items;
    }
```

Its working for me. But I have an issue when Postion. I dont know how to resolve.